# Firefox connection timing out when using Jmeter proxy

Tags: jmeter

I am learning JMeter and trying to record a transaction using HTTP Test Script recorder.I am also using Firefox as the browser.While I am using port 8080 as the proxy in Jmeter, localhost and 8080 as host and port in firefox proxy settings, and 3000 as the port for the website in HTTP request defaults. During the recording the process , I am getting connection timeout exception in Firefox. Please help.

Here are some of the screenshots showing what I am doing actually.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Step1:** Open your **Firefox browser** and from Network Connection settings configure the **proxy server** as `HTTP Proxy: 127.0.0.1`, `Port: 8888`

[image]

**Step2:** Run your **`Jmeter.bat`** file and open **`Templates`** under File dropdown list and click "Create".

[image]

**Step3:** Expand Work Bench and select `HTTP(s) Test Script Recorder`. And click `Start` at the bottom of the page.You will have two pop up to **Allow Firewall** and **Temporary Root CA Certification Installation**.Allow all those and now go to your browser and do your browser activity.When it's done `Stop` the HTTP(s) Test Script Recorder.

**Step4:** You will get the recorded script in JMeter with all your activity in the browser.It will automatically update under `Thread Group`.This script will contain all your page requests during browsing activity. Sample script after recording is shown below.

[image]

I am using `JMeter 2.13` but the procedure is similar in `JMeter 3.0`.

Otherwise, you could use **[BlazeMeter's Google Chrome extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732579-Chrome-Extension)** for to record or run a performance test.